# Flash messages not showing on update error with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have devise and have added in username to the registration process. 
Ive also added in validations for username presence and length inside the mdoel.

On sign up if I don't put a Username in the validation kicks in and the flash message appears but on Edit User if i don't put a Username the validation kicks in but no flash appears. I have flash in `'layout/application'` So it is present on every page.

Here is a helper method i have :

```
    module DeviseHelper
      def devise_error_messages!
        if resource.errors.full_messages.any?
          flash.now[:danger] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        end
        return ''
      end
    end
```

Any ideas would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Devise error helper method overwrites only for design related changes see the devise error helper method

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      count: resource.errors.count,
                      resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

   def devise_error_messages?
     !resource.errors.empty?
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i went and had look at the code for the update action in the registrations controller and found that i could add code to set the flash after its failed to update.

```
def update
      self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
      prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)
      resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource_updated
        if is_flashing_format?
          flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
            :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
          set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
        end
        bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name
        respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence <<<< RIGHT HERE
        clean_up_passwords resource
        set_minimum_password_length
        respond_with resource
      end
    end
```

Here is the code incase anyone else has this issue.